# Is there a ring $R$ such that $(R,+) \cong S^{1}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, complex-numbers, roots-of-unity, positive-characteristic

Here is the question I wanted to answer letter(c) of it:

Let $R$ be a ring (with 1), and let $H$ be the cyclic subgroup of $(R,+)$ generated by $1.$ The characteristic of $R$ is $n$ if $H\cong \mathbb{Z}_{n},$ and is $0$ if $H \cong \mathbb{Z}.$\
(a) Show that, if $a \in R$ has additive order $m,$ then $m$ divides the characteristic of $R.$\
(b) Prove or disprove: If the characteristic of $R$ is $0,$ then $(R,+)$ is torsion free.\
(c) Is there a ring $R$ such that $(R,+) \cong S^{1}$ ?

**Here is a solution to letter $(c)$:**

The answer is No. And here is the justification:

```
$S^{1}$ is defined as $\{ z \in \mathbb{C}^{*}\ :\ |z|=1 \}$ and if $a,b \in S^1,$ then $|a| = |b| = 1$ but $|a + b| \leq |a| + |b| = 2$ and so $a + b$ is not necessarily in $S^1.$\\

On the other hand, $(R, +)$ form an additive group and so it is closed under addition.

Hence, $$(R,+) \ncong S^1.$$
```

**Here is a hint to the correct solution:**

Assume $na = 0$ and $nb = 1$ for $a,b \in R, n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}.$ Then $$a = a. (nb) = (na). b = 0 .b = 0 $$

Also, I found a solution here [Isomorphism of $S^1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3823431/isomorphism-of-s1)

**My questions are:**

1- In the link I mentioned, the author is using the idea that $S^1$ is divisible, I do not know why that is correct, could anyone explain that for me please?

2-Also, I do not understand the general idea of the solution, could anyone explain it for me please?

3- My understanding is that we are using the idea that $R$ is a ring with unit so it has multiplicative and additive identity, but why $a$ can not be zero in the hint?

Comment: 1. It is correct, because this is the definition of "divisible". Note that $S^1$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$, which is divisible. So just follow every line of the proof by Maxime, or one of the other answers. 2. If you don't know a mathematical term, look it up in wikipedia. Everything is explained at the duplicate.

Comment: What is the meaning of divisible ..... does it means that every element has an inverse?@DietrichBurde .... No I do not see that it is explained thoroughly and in a logic order .... It is not a duplicate I am already asking about the question I linked which you considered my question a duplicate of it.

Comment: Dear math, "What is the meaning of divisible". This is explained in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisible_group), It is a very useful term. I am sure you can read this alone, without our help. You are right, your question need not be a duplicate, but you should ask it then differently, not again the title question. Because the title question really has been answered completely in the duplicate (where it is assumed of course, that you look up new words in a dictionary). And "divisible" for groups is a term like "prime" in elementary number theory. One should know it.

Comment: @DietrichBurde ok thank you .... but I need to understand the general idea of the solution and I am asking something about the hint I got.